# How can you reliably test if a value is equal to NaN?

Tags: javascript

I only know to use isNaN to test if a value is equal to NaN. Is it really reliable?

Comment: see here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

Answer (score 2):

The NaN property represents a value that is “not a number”. This special value results from an operation that could not be performed either because one of the operands was non-numeric (e.g., "abc" / 4), or because the result of the operation is non-numeric(e.g., an attempt to divide by zero).

While this seems straightforward enough, there are a couple of somewhat surprising characteristics of NaN that can result in hair-pulling bugs if one is not aware of them.

For one thing, although NaN means “not a number”, its type is, believe it or not, Number:

```
console.log(typeof NaN === "number");  // logs "true"
```

Additionally, NaN compared to anything – even itself! – is false:

```
console.log(NaN === NaN);  // logs "false"
```

A semi-reliable way to test whether a number is equal to NaN is with the built-in function isNaN(), 
but even using [isNaN() is an imperfect solution.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Confusing_special-case_behavior)

A better solution would either be to use value !== value, which would only produce true if the value is equal to NaN. Also, ES6 offers a new Number.isNaN() function, which is a different and more reliable than the old global isNaN() function.

Comment: How about `typeof value === "number" && isNaN(value)`?

Comment: It's a good solution as well.